# Reverse Z depth buffer projection matrix computation

Tags: c++, matrix

Can someone explain to me how to compute a projection matrix suitable for reverse Z depth buffer?

I know that I have to map the near plane to 1 and the far plane to 0 but I really can't get a matrix that works.

This is the code I use to compute my "normal" projection matrix (working):

```
float fovYRad = DegToRad(fov * 0.5f);
float tanHalfFovy = tanf(fovYRad);
float aspect = width / height;

m[0] = 1.0f / tanHalfFovy;  m[1] = 0.0f;                    m[2] = 0.0f;                                    m[3] = 0.0f;
m[4] = 0.0f;                m[5] = aspect / tanHalfFovy;    m[6] = 0.0f;                                    m[7] = 0.0f;
m[8] = 0.0f;                m[9] = 0.0f;                    m[10] = (zNear + zFar) / (zNear - zFar);        m[11] = -1.0f;
m[12] = 0.0f;               m[13] = 0.0f;                   m[14] = (2.0f * zNear * zFar) / (zNear - zFar); m[15] = 0.0f;
```

And this is my attempt to compute a reverse Z projection matrix (not working):

```
float fovYRad = DegToRad(fov * 0.5f);
float tanHalfFovy = tanf(fovYRad);
float aspect = width / height;

m[0] = 1.0f / tanHalfFovy;  m[1] = 0.0f;                    m[2] = 0.0f;                                m[3] = 0.0f;
m[4] = 0.0f;                m[5] = aspect / tanHalfFovy;    m[6] = 0.0f;                                m[7] = 0.0f;
m[8] = 0.0f;                m[9] = 0.0f;                    m[10] = zNear / (zFar - zNear);             m[11] = -1.0f;
m[12] = 0.0f;               m[13] = 0.0f;                   m[14] = (zNear * zFar) / (zFar - zNear);    m[15] = 0.0f;
```

Comment: That second matrix seems to be working as advertised on my end (when tested using glm). Your normal matrix maps to `[-1, 1]`. So perhaps you have code further down the line that expects `[1, -1]` once inverted.

Comment: Actually I tested my matrices setting them up with `zNear = 0.1` and `zFar = 100` and multipliying them by `[0,0,0.1]` and `[0,0,100]` and these vertices are mapped neither to `[1,-1]` nor to `[-1,1]`. They are actually mapped to `0,0,3` and `0,0,1` using the normal projection Matrix; `0,0,-1` and `0,0,-0.002` using the reverse Z projection matrix

Comment: These are right-handed perspective matrices that look down the negative z axis. You need to test with `0,0,-0.1,1` and `0,0,-100,1` for the test vertices

Comment: Yeah, I found that out a few hours ago and forgot to write it down here